# Displaying background images of achor links horizontally

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I am trying to display different icons in my webpage like following:

[image]

I have tried the following HTML and CSS code but is it is displaying the icons vertically like following:

[image]

HTML

```
<div id="socialNetwork">
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank" class="twitter"></a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="facebook"></a>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank" class="linkedIn"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#socialNetwork a{
display:block;
height:35px; 
width:34px;
text-indent:-9999px;

}

.twitter {
background-image:url(twitter.png);
}

.twitter:hover {
background-image:url(twitter_hover.png);
}

.facebook {
background-image:url(facebook.png);
}

.facebook:hover {
background-image:url(facebook_hover.png);
}

.linkedIn {
background-image:url(linkedIn.png);
}

.linkedIn:hover {
background-image:url(linkedIn_hover.png);
}
```

I think the code is displaying the icons vertically because I have `display:block;`  in `#socialNetwork a` . But if I remove  `display:block;` the icons do not appear.

Could you please show me how to make the icons appear horizontally like in the first image above?

Thanks

Comment: `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying using:

```
#socialNetwork a { display: inline-block; }
```